# How can I automate Data input and drop down selection on my web form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a few simple inputs like length, width, and say a dropdown called fabric.

Once a user inputs the Length and Width, the Fabric list is updated via an AJAX call to my FIRST DB. To show only those fabrics that fit your dimensions.

If a user enters these values themselves, the system works perfectly fine.

HOWEVER If I want to AUTO LOAD the USER INPUT from a SECOND Database, I have to first set the Length and Width to the AUTOMATIC values, then I trigger the change function, which should update the Fabric List, and THEN the fabric list should be loaded from the FIRST DB and the selected Fabric should be picked based on the SECOND DB.

The issue I am having is that the length, width, fabric are all loaded at once, and then the trigger function is called, which overwrites the selected fabric.

Can anyone please advise me on how I can solve this issue.

TLDR: Have 2 Length, width inputs, and a 3rd Fabric List, which is updated via AJAX Call. I want to be able to automate the Data entry and selection.

I've tried using callbacks, promises and waiting using wait.

MY HTML

```
<input id="Width" type="number" min="1" step="1" onchange="processWidth();">
<input id="Length" type="number" min="1" step="1" onchange="processLength();">                   
<select id="fabric_group" onchange="fabricSeriesFilter();">
   "OPTIONS LOADED VIA AJAX POST USING PHP AND FIRST MYSQL DB"
</select>
```

MY JS

```
function add_details(){
  enterValue(Width, 45);
  $('#Width').trigger('change');
  enterValue(Length, 60);
  $('#Length').trigger('change');
}

function add_group(){
    $('#fabric_group').val('privacy');
    $('#fabric_group').trigger('change')
}
```

I expect the Length and Width to be populated from SECOND DB, then the filtering AJAX call would update my Select from the FIRST DB, THEN the option should be picked from the SECOND DB.

I get the Length and Width Populated, but the select isn't being picked.

Comment: How are you implementing the ajax? What do all the inline javascript functions look like?